# Pass Value Onclick Checkbox to controller codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to CI and i am having issues in following code:
My Controller shows all the values of countries dynamically from DB, i need to pass value onclicking particular chechbox to my controller

My view:

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
        foreach ( $countryDetails as $row ) 
        {
        echo '<input id="country" type="checkbox" name="country" class="unique" value="'.$row->country_id.'" onclick="">'.$row->country_name.'<br/>';
        }
        ?>
    <script>
    $('input.unique').click(function() {
    $('input.unique:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
    </script>
    <script>
```

and my Controller is

```
public function index()
{       
$this->view_data['countryDetails'] = $this->get_county_model->getCountryDetails();


$this->load->view('get_country' , $this->view_data );
}
```

Comment: its done using ajax call...

Comment: CAn i get sample code? i already tried my codes!

Comment: u want to pass the value of the checkbox on click event rite?

Comment: Yes, on clicking checkbox, the value of the checkbox should be pass to controller!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  value 1<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="value1"/>
  value 2<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="value2"/> 
  value 3<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="value3"/>
  value 4<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="value4"/>
```

Jquery Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).on('click','.chkbox',function(){
      var id=this.value;

       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        context: "application/json",
        data: {id:id},
        url: "http://localhost/xyz/index.php/controller_name/function_name",
        success: function(msg) 
        {
            alert('result from controller');
        }
    })
   });

 });
```

Controller

```
 public function function_name()
 {
   $id=$this->input->post('id');
   //now use the $id variable for the desired purpose.
 }
```

Comment: this code is not redirecting me to alert! I guess some code for checked boxes is used.

Comment: part1 of view:<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
   foreach ( $countryDetails as $row ) 
   {
   echo '<input id="country" type="checkbox" name="country" class="unique" value="'.$row->country_id.'">'.$row->country_name.'<br/>';
   }
   ?>
  <script>
  $('input.unique').click(function() {
     $('input.unique:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
  });
  </script>

Comment: part 2 of view: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

       $(document).on('click','.unique',function(){
        var id=this.value;

         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          context: "application/json",
          data: {id:id},
          url: "http://localhost/index.php/fetch_country/fetch",
          success: function(msg) 
          {
              alert('echop ');
          }
      });
     });
   });
  </script>
   
  </body>
  </html>

Comment: controller: public function fetch()
 {
  $id=$this->input->post('id');
  echo ('done');
 }

Comment: u dint specify your URL correctly it should be like http://www.localhost/your_website_name/index.php/contoller_name/function_name/  and what error you are facing?

Comment: ON clicking the Checkbox i am not getting the alert i.e my value is not being getting passed. Also after rectifying URL still I am not getting results.